# React-Native "app is not installed" on some Android devices

Tags: android, react-native

Our react-native app is working on all devices correctly but some Android devices can't install the app and after trying to install the app, the message is appeared on screen which says: "App is not installed".
I don't know what the problem is and I couldn't find the right solution so I decided to ask here.
I want to know what scenarios can be happened for this issue to look for them and fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

- Enable developer mode on device.
- In "Module: app" build.gradle check "minSdkVersion = ..." to be same (or lower) as devices

If non works can you share some specifications of the device that doesn't work?

Comment: Our minSdkVersion is 16 and the device is Samsung SM-J730F.

Comment: Can you provide more information's? Log, or prtsc the error